# Label alignment. Same height. Bootstrap 4 - Forms

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, label

Using Bootstrap 4 / Forms: Is there any easy way to align labels, if the others labels **in the same form-row** are very long?

https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/tL1afnqj/4/

EXAMPLES:

Bad align of labels

[image: Bad align of labels]

Correct alignment

[image: Correct alignment]

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputEmail4">Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email</label>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `align-items-end` class with `form-row` like this-
`<div class="form-row align-items-end">` See the example below

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="p-5">
  <div class="form-row align-items-end">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Woooow nice job!